# Errores laravel

Tags: php, laravel

estoy trabajando un proyecto en laravel 6, definí mi request personalizado y definí un campo unique

```js
return [
            'titulo' => 'required|min:5|max:50|unique:contenidos',
            'contenido' => 'required|min:5|max:2000',
            'seccion_id'=>'required'
        ];
```

cuando el meotodo store hace la validación y detecta que hay un titulo igual en la misma tabla me envia un error que imprimo desde blade asi

```js
@if ($errors->any())
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{ $error }}
</div>
@endforeach
@endif
```

como puedo personalizar este mensaje según el error, porque mi pregunta es que tipos de error hay en laravel, con eso puedo hacer un if y dependiendo el error mandar un mensaje
gracias a todos

Comment: Hay tantos errores de validación como reglas. Por lo que veo, supongo que estás validando en una clase que extiende de FormRequest. Si es así puedes personalizar los mensajes en la función [messages()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#customizing-the-error-messages)

Comment: tienes dos opciones, enviar un error bag https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#named-error-bags o puedes cambiar el mensaje en los archivos de lenguaje que estan en /resources/lang